# Merging different svg elements using svgwrite

Tags: python-3.x, svg, svgwrite

I am using SVGWrite to create different files with certain paths in the following way:

```
dwg = svgwrite.Drawing(filename=save_path)
dwg.viewbox(width=view_width, height=view_height)
path = svgwrite.path.Path(p)
dwg.add(path)
```

I now need to "merge" those different drawing into one svg file, where I can choose the position of each drawing. So something like :

```
for draw in dwgs:
    newSvg.add(draw(insert(x,y)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I tried svg-stack but ran into different problems.